# How to handle options when opening a file passed as argument?

Tags: bash, shell-script, arguments

I am trying to open a file through a script; as long as I pass the file as the first argument there are no problems; for instance:

```
$ cat textExample.txt 
Much I marvelled this ungainly fowl to hear discourse so plainly,
Though its answer little meaning- little relevancy bore;
For we cannot help agreeing that no living human being
Ever yet was blessed with seeing bird above his chamber door-
Bird or beast upon the sculptured bust above his chamber door,
With such name as "Nevermore."
$ ./tester.sh textExample.txt 
BEGIN PROGRAM
parse file
For we cannot help agreeing that no living human being
```

where tester.sh is written like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# options
optstring=fh
Feature=0
Help=0
while getopts $optstring opt
do
  case $opt in
    f) Feature=1;;
    h) Help=1 ;;
    *) echo WRONG && exit 1 ;;
  esac
done

if [[ $Feature == 1 ]] ; then
    echo "This is a feature of the program"
elif [[ $Help == 1 ]] ; then
    echo "This is the help page"
fi

echo "BEGIN PROGRAM"
# assign file name
file=$1
echo "parse file"
grep 'cannot help' $file

exit 0
```

Only the -h flag works because there is an exit statement:

```
$ ./tester.sh -h
This is the help page
$ ./tester.sh -f
This is a feature of the program
BEGIN PROGRAM
parse file
grep: option requires an argument -- 'f'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

Therefore, I modified the script introducing a step to check if the argument is a flag:

```
#!/bin/bash

# options
optstring=fh
Feature=0
Help=0
while getopts $optstring opt
do
  case $opt in
    f) Feature=1;;
    h) Help=1 ;;
    n) Custom_name=$OPTARG ;;
    *) echo WRONG && exit 1 ;;
  esac
done

if [[ $Feature == 1 ]] ; then
    echo "This is a feature of the program"
elif [[ $Help == 1 ]] ; then
    echo "This is the help page"
    exit
fi

for i in $@ ; do
    if [[ "${i}" =~ "-" ]] ; then
        true
    else
        input=$i
    fi
done


echo "BEGIN PROGRAM"
# assign file name
echo "parse file"
grep 'cannot help' $input

exit 0
```

and the result is:

```
$ ./tester.sh -f
This is a feature of the program
BEGIN PROGRAM
parse file
$ ./tester.sh -f textExample.txt 
This is a feature of the program
BEGIN PROGRAM
parse file
For we cannot help agreeing that no living human being
```

The problem is: if I add another argument to save the line to a file of a name of choice, I have another problem. Modifying the file in:

```
#!/bin/bash

# options
optstring=fhn:
Feature=0
Help=0
output=
while getopts $optstring opt
do
  case $opt in
    f) Feature=1;;
    h) Help=1 ;;
    n) output=$OPTARG ;;
    *) echo WRONG && exit 1 ;;
  esac
done

if [[ $Feature == 1 ]] ; then
    echo "This is a feature of the program"
elif [[ $Help == 1 ]] ; then
    echo "This is the help page"
    exit
fi

for i in $@ ; do
    if [[ "${i}" =~ "-" ]] ; then
        true
    else
        input=$i
    fi
done


echo "BEGIN PROGRAM"
# assign file name
echo "parse file"
if [[ -z $output ]] ; then
    grep 'cannot help' $input
else
    grep 'cannot help' $input > $output
fi

exit 0
```

the output is:

```
$ ./tester.sh -f textExample.txt 
This is a feature of the program
BEGIN PROGRAM
parse file
For we cannot help agreeing that no living human being
$ ./tester.sh -f -n my_file textExample.txt 
This is a feature of the program
BEGIN PROGRAM
parse file
$ ./tester.sh -n my_file textExample.txt 
BEGIN PROGRAM
parse file
```

That is: there is no input file anymore, bash is looking at the argument my_file as the input file.

I have been thinking to bracket the output file in single or double quotes and check for their presence, but I can't escape the quote, thus I get an error. Modifying the section:

```
for i in $@ ; do
    if [[ "${i}" =~ "-" ]] ; then
        true
    elif [[ "${i}" =~ \' ]] ; then
        true
    else
        input=$i
    fi
done
```

I get:

```
$ ./tester.sh -n 'my_file' textExample.txt 
BEGIN PROGRAM
parse file
```

That is, bash does not recognize the quotes in the argument. I tried different options such as "\'", '\'' etc as well as $i, "$i".

Is there a way to check the presence of quotes in an argument?
Or a better way to handle arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After processing the options with `getopts`, the variable `OPTIND` is set to the *index* of the first non-option argument, so do this:

```
while getopts $optstring opt; do
    #... 
done
# now, remove the options from the positional parameters
shift $((OPTIND-1))
```

Now, `$1` contains the filename.

Comment: Perfect! it works even without the quote markings:  `./tester.sh -n 'my_file' textExample.txt `
`BEGIN PROGRAM
parse file`
`$ cat my_file `
`For we cannot help agreeing that no living human being`
`$ ./tester.sh -n my_file textExample.txt` 
`BEGIN PROGRAM
parse file`
`$ cat my_file `
`For we cannot help agreeing that no living human being`. Thank you!